# How to ensure std::call_once really is only called once

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Some code I'm working with uses std::call_once so that some initialization only occurs once. However, there are global objects with constructors that can end up calling the initialization code.

In the following sample, call_once actually gets called twice. I guess it's because the once_flag constructor hasn't ran before it gets used. Is there a way around this so that some initialization code only gets called once without having to prohibit globals?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Init();

class Global
{
public:
    Global()
    {
        Init();
    }
};

Global global;

once_flag flag;

void Init()
{
    call_once(flag, []{  cout << "hello" << endl;  });
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Init();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
hello
hello
```

Comment: I only see "hello" output once for GCC and Clang.

Comment: @remyabel - Hmm, I wonder then if this is a micosoft STL bug.

Comment: Your `using namespace std;` defeats the namespace mechanism of C++. It also makes your code harder to understand. Don't do that. Rather, `using std::once_flag;` etc. That is, import specific symbols; don't dump the namespace. Also, for standard C++ style, avoid capitalizing function names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the specs, `once_flag` should have a trivial `constexpr` constructor (for example see here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag ). With this in place, if it is global/static, it is not actually "constructed" (no actual function is executed), but more like "value initialized" - like any global/static POD type. In that case it is not possible to have any constructor run "before" this `once_flag` is properly initialized. Given your comment about using MSVC, I guess it can be a bug in the implementation...

EDIT:
According to the comment below, `constexpr` is not supported on MSVC at all, so your options are really limited in here... If you have everything in one file, just put your `once_flag` "above" everything that uses it - the constructors in a file are executed in the order of declaration of objects. If you have the users spread across different files, your only option is to use a function that provides access to static internal `once_flag` - like in this answer http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html .

Comment: VS2013 does not support `constexpr` at all

Comment: I wonder if a static function will have the problem though (as my version of MSVC doesn't support magic statics) that the once_flag could be constructed twice in the face of multiple threads. Hmm.. sounds like a job for std::call_once to ensure that doesn't happen, hmm, hang on a minute. :)

Comment: `once_flag` constructor is not trivial at all: it sets the internal state to indicate that no function has been called yet.

Comment: @AntonSavin - it must be `constexpr`, which means it must be _REALLY_ simple, so simple that this type can be treated almost like a POD from this point of view.

Comment: Indeed, the signature `constexpr once_flag() noexcept;` leaves no room for interpretation on a conformant toolchain.

Comment: @AntonSavin The `constexpr` constructor guarantees *constant initialization*, which as a form of static initialization must be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.